# Class destructor is being called twice

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, scope, destructor

I have the following program:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
protected:
    A() { cout << "Executing A()" << endl; }
public:
    ~A() { cout << "Executing ~A()" << endl; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() { cout << "Executing B()" << endl; }
    ~B() { cout << "Executing ~B()" << endl; }
};

class C : public B {
public:
    C() { cout << "Executing C()" << endl; }
    ~C() { cout << "Executing ~C()" << endl; }
};

void someFunc() {
    A a = C();
}

int main() {
    someFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

which prints the following:

[image: Print screen]

Why is `~A()` called twice?

Comment: Odds are your assignment is triggering a copy constructor (when you assign `C()` to `a` but your output code has no visibility into that (or to the assignment operator).  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29

Comment: @Mati: Don't use an image to paste plain-text. Just paste plain-text instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The destructor for `A` is called twice because there are two objects that need to be destroyed. [By printing something when the copy or move constructor is called you can verify this:](http://ideone.com/7G7b8l)

> ```
> class A {
> protected:
>   A() { cout << "Executing A()" << endl; }
> public:
>   A(const A &) { cout << "Executing A(const A &)" << endl; }
>   // with recent compilers, you could also try A(A &&)
>   ~A() { cout << "Executing ~A()" << endl; }
> };
> ```

Output:

```
Executing A()
Executing B()
Executing C()
Executing A(const A &)
Executing ~C()
Executing ~B()
Executing ~A()
Executing ~A()
```

Basically, `A a = C();` doesn't do what you might think it does. It creates an anonymous `C` object, and then creates `a` as an `A` object, copying from the just-created anonymous object. It does not let `a` somehow point to a real `C` object.

A variable declared as `A` is *always* an `A`, never any derived type. To get something to that effect, you would need to use pointers or references.

```
const A &a = C();
```

Here, `a` is *not* an `A` object. This creates the same anonymous `C` object as before, but then makes `a` a reference to that anonymous object, instead of attempting to create a new `A` object.

Comment: Technically, the original code should invoke a move :)

Comment: How can I avoid this temporary object creation? How can I make `A` be the same object as `C`? (Same address)

Comment: @T.C. Assuming a C++11-conforming implementation (or newer), you're right.

Comment: I believe you want `A& a = C();`

Comment: @Havenard Close. `const A& a = C();` is valid, as is `A&& a = C();` (as of C++11), but not `A& a = C();`. Now edited into my answer.